# Using WinForms in JetBrains Rider on Linux

Tags: c#, linux, winforms, jetbrains-rider

While I can compile WinForms applications using Mono on the command-line, it's not possible in Rider.

It's okay that there's no solution/project template available, or the designer, that doesn't matter much. But I can't even use `System.Windows.Forms` when writing the code myself.

Is there some way to tell Rider to use the installed WinForms library?

The simple code I try to build:

```
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Program
{
    [STAThread]
    public static void Main()
    {
    }
}
```

Build output (from Rider):

```
Build with surface heuristics started at 22:13:46
Use build tool: /home/arrow/.dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/MSBuild.dll
CONSOLE: MSBuild version 17.4.0+18d5aef85 for .NET
CONSOLE: Build started 2/9/2024 10:13:46PM.
CONSOLE: Project "/tmp/JetBrainsPerUserTemp-1000-1/Sytivel.proj" on node 1 (default targets).
CONSOLE: ControllerTarget:
CONSOLE:   Run controller from /home/arrow/.local/share/JetBrains/Toolbox/apps/rider/lib/ReSharperHost/JetBrains.Platform.MsBuildTask.v17.dll
0>------- Started building project: ConsoleApp2
/home/arrow/.dotnet/dotnet exec "/home/arrow/.dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Roslyn/bincore/csc.dll" /noconfig /unsafe- /checked- /nowarn:1701,1702,IL2121,1701,1702 /fullpaths /nostdlib+ /errorreport:prompt /warn:7 /define:TRACE;DEBUG;NET;NET7_0;NETCOREAPP;NET5_0_OR_GREATER;NET6_0_OR_GREATER;NET7_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP1_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_1_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP2_2_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_0_OR_GREATER;NETCOREAPP3_1_OR_GREATER /highentropyva+ /nullable:enable /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/Microsoft.CSharp.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/Microsoft.VisualBasic.Core.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/Microsoft.Win32.Registry.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/mscorlib.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/netstandard.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.AppContext.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Buffers.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Collections.Concurrent.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Collections.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Collections.Immutable.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Collections.Specialized.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.ComponentModel.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Configuration.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Console.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Core.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Data.Common.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Data.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.Process.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Drawing.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Drawing.Primitives.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Formats.Asn1.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Formats.Tar.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Globalization.Calendars.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Globalization.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Globalization.Extensions.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.IO.Compression.Brotli.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.IO.Compression.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.IO.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.IO.FileSystem.AccessControl.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.IO.FileSystem.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.IO.Pipes.AccessControl.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.IO.Pipes.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Linq.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Linq.Expressions.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Linq.Parallel.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Linq.Queryable.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Memory.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Http.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Http.Json.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.HttpListener.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Mail.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.NameResolution.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Ping.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Primitives.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Quic.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Requests.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Security.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.ServicePoint.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.Sockets.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.WebClient.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.WebProxy.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Net.WebSockets.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Numerics.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Numerics.Vectors.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.ObjectModel.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.Emit.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.Emit.ILGeneration.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.Emit.Lightweight.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.Extensions.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.Metadata.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.Primitives.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Resources.Reader.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Resources.Writer.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Extensions.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Handles.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.InteropServices.JavaScript.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Intrinsics.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Loader.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Numerics.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Serialization.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Security.AccessControl.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Claims.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.OpenSsl.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Security.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Principal.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Security.SecureString.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.ServiceModel.Web.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.ServiceProcess.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Text.Encoding.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Text.Encodings.Web.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Text.Json.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Channels.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Overlapped.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Tasks.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Thread.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Threading.Timer.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Transactions.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Transactions.Local.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.ValueTuple.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Web.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Web.HttpUtility.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Windows.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.Linq.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.Serialization.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.XDocument.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.XPath.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll /reference:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/ref/net7.0/WindowsBase.dll /debug+ /debug:portable /filealign:512 /optimize- /out:obj/Debug/net7.0/ConsoleApp2.dll /refout:obj/Debug/net7.0/refint/ConsoleApp2.dll /target:exe /warnaserror- /utf8output /deterministic+ /langversion:11.0 /analyzerconfig:obj/Debug/net7.0/ConsoleApp2.GeneratedMSBuildEditorConfig.editorconfig /analyzer:/home/arrow/.dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/../analyzers/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.NetAnalyzers.dll /analyzer:/home/arrow/.dotnet/sdk/7.0.100/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/targets/../analyzers/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.NetAnalyzers.dll /analyzer:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/analyzers/dotnet/cs/Microsoft.Interop.JavaScript.JSImportGenerator.dll /analyzer:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/analyzers/dotnet/cs/Microsoft.Interop.LibraryImportGenerator.dll /analyzer:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/analyzers/dotnet/cs/Microsoft.Interop.SourceGeneration.dll /analyzer:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/analyzers/dotnet/cs/System.Text.Json.SourceGeneration.dll /analyzer:/home/arrow/.dotnet/packs/Microsoft.NETCore.App.Ref/7.0.0/analyzers/dotnet/cs/System.Text.RegularExpressions.Generator.dll Program.cs obj/Debug/net7.0/ConsoleApp2.GlobalUsings.g.cs "obj/Debug/net7.0/.NETCoreApp,Version=v7.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs" obj/Debug/net7.0/ConsoleApp2.AssemblyInfo.cs /warnaserror+:NU1605,SYSLIB0011
0>Program.cs(1,22): Error CS0234 : The type or namespace name 'Forms' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
0>------- Finished building project: ConsoleApp2. Succeeded: False. Errors: 1. Warnings: 0
Build completed in 00:00:01.533
```

And Rider itself doesn't recognize it either:
[image: Rider not recognizing System.Windows.Form]

Comment: Just looks like it's not using Mono, but the .NET SDK (which does *not* come with winforms). Are you sure you have Rider configured properly to use Mono?

Comment: @NPras No I'm not sure about the configuration. Or how to change it. That's why I posted the question... :)

Comment: What Runtime is selected when you try to edit your Run/Debug Configuration? When there ist something like <Automatic> selected, select "Mono". If this is not showing up in the dropdown add a custom Runtime with your installation path of Mono. You probably need to add the `System.Windows.Forms` Assembly to your project as well to get it running.

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt I have changed my Runtime to Mono, I have created a .NET Framework 4.8 console project. The assemblies can't be found (so I can't even build a program with an empty `Main` function) with that project, and I don't know where to change the path to those or how to import new assemblies. I don't want to set up a VM and get new Window and VS licenses just to do some simple applications.

Comment: That sounds like a good starting point. You can add assemblies on the left site in the `Explorer`. Just expand `Dependencies` and right-click `Assemblies` and click on `Reference`. You should see a list of all the possible Assemblies you can add from Mono. `System.Windows.Forms` should be in this list.

Comment: @JonasWeinhardt Thank you, that kind of helped me on the right way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I managed to get it to work:

1. Create a new .NET / .NET Core console project. Leave everything as default
2. Go into the project properties (right-click on the project, not solution, and select properties)
3. For "Target Framework" select the three dots, deselect `net7.0` and select `net4.8`
4. Go back to the project properties, to set the language version to at least C# 10.0
5. Right-click on `Dependencies` and select `Reference...`. Add the wanted assemblies (like `System.Windows.Form`). Also add `System.Net.Http` (which is needed by the auto-generated files from the project template)
6. Build and run your WinForm application!